# Сертификаты КриптоПро CSP 5

Tags: ubuntu, криптография, сертификат, криптопро

Установил на Ubuntu 18.04 программу КриптоПро CSP 5, для работы с ней нужно установить личный и сторонние сертификаты. Где их взять, зачем они нужны?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установить сертификаты можно через программу CPTools - будет в меню, если установили полный комплект. Личный сертификат берется с купленого в [Удостоверяющем центре](https://digital.gov.ru/ru/activity/govservices/certification_authority/) токена. Токен как флешка (меньше мегабайта), только сконструирована для использования для электронной подписи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этот токен записывается подпись в удостоверяющем центре, цена зависит от назначения подписи, https://tensor.ru/ivanovo/uc например.

Сертификат устанавливается в 2 клика "установить сертификат" -> Далее в cptools или через консоль https://estp.ru/test_eds/cert_install_linux/

Сторонние сертификаты берутся на порталах, с которыми хотите работать по ГОСТ.

Налоговая https://www.nalog.ru/rn77/about_fts/uc_fns/

зачем они нужны? - **для удостоверения личности** при подаче заявлений и оформлении сделок.
Мои заметки как что донастроить https://github.com/alex-eri/linux-gost/blob/master/debian-gost.md

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но можно подробнее, что за токен и как из него можно получить сертификат. Приобретенная лицензия на ПО является этим самым токеном?

Comment: добавил про токен. нет - лицензия это не токен